# how to iterate through data in Blade views (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: loops, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Within Blade, `{{ dd(get_defined_vars()['__data']) }}` gives me this output:

```
array:6 [▼
  "__env" => Factory {#152 ▶}
  "app" => Application {#2 ▶}
  "errors" => ViewErrorBag {#145 ▶}
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "question" => "question 3"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "question" => "question 2"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "question" => "question 1"
  ]
]
```

My controller builds this data like so:

```
foreach ($questions as $question) {
        $answer = [
            'question' => $question->question,
        ];
        $answers[] = $answer;
    }
    return view('results')->with($answers);
```

How do I iterate over this in Blade to display the 3 questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job

From laravel documentation

> When passing information in this manner, $data should be an array with
>   key/value pairs

**In Controller**

```
return view('results')->with('answers', $answers);
```

**In blade**

```
 @foreach($answers as $answer)
         {{ $answer['question'] }}
 @endforeach
```

Have a look at

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#passing-data-to-views